# Why is $t=\frac 3 2$ in $1+t=\sqrt{4+t^2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am confused about solving $1+t=\sqrt{4+t^2}$.

When I solve it per hand I come to the conclusion that $t$ can be everything.

$$\begin{align*}
1+t =\sqrt{4+t^2}& \qquad | \cdot^2 \tag{1} \\
1+t^2 = 4+t^2 & \qquad | -t^2 \tag{2} \\
1 = 4  \tag{3}
\end{align*}$$

However wolfram alpha tells me the result is $\frac 3 2$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your second step is wrong. $1+2t+t^2=4+t^2$ $=>$ $t=3/2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1+t=\sqrt{4+t^2}
\implies (1+t)^2=1+2t+t^2=4+t^2
\implies 2t=3
\implies t=3/2$

Answer (score 2):

Your error is here:

$$(1+t)^2 = 1 + 2t + t^2 \ne 1 + t^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** : Square both sides; then (1+t)^2 = 4+t^2. Expand the left handside ... but what is (a+b)^2 when expanded ? Can you continue with this ?